# How does a Mac identify an Infinity USB Foot Control?

Tags: usb, hardware, peripheral

I do some light transcription work and I am looking at purchasing a second-hand [Infinity USB Foot Pedal (IN-USB-2)](https://www.altoedge.com/pedals/vec-infinity-foot-pedals.html) to transcribe from MP3 audio and MP4 video files.

How does a Mac identify an Infinity USB Foot Control? If it is recognized as a standard keyboard, I would prefer to use [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to program the foot control to emulate the media keys on my keyboard.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but would like to bring the following alternative to your attention: a guitar midi pedal / footswitch, a midi to usb converter and some midi to key mapping software (e.g. midistroke, bome or midishortcut). It can be cheaper than specific transcribing hardware and it gives you more freedom to configure.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke would that type of setup be less than $30? I have been able to find the Infinity pedal for around that price and Karabiner-Elements is free software. Also, I would be needing at least 3 switches for Play/Pause, Rewind, and Fast-Forward.

Comment: Hmm, afraid not... I bought a secondhand behringer fbc1010 (which has 10 switches and pedals that allow me to scroll) for $35, already had a midi-to-usb dongle lying around and used a trial version of bome midi pro.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution to this? Karabiner elements isn't detecting Infinity USB Foot Pedal as a Device. Although ExpressScribe is able to detect it as a Controller.